# Finding differential equation which is satisfied by system of parabolas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone please tell me what is the reason behind y not being 0 ? Is it because of the slope of the parabola does not exist when $ x =-a$ and only at $x = -a$, $y=0$.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I will type the material once I get the keyboard. Actually, I could not type because I am posting from my touch screen phone.  Please help me now.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient is undefined at $x = -a$, but still exists for $x = a$.

Although your partly correct, the solution most likely states "$[\because y ≠ 0]$", as a form of reasoning to support their division by $y$ on the equation that it is tagged with.

See that at $(5)$ (from beginning), dividing $y$ means that $y$ can no longer take the value $0$, otherwise its zero-division. Hence, it was omitted from the original domain of $y$, $y \in \mathbb{R} \to y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$